# Cannot Install Windows 10 22h2 as guest VirtualBox 7 on MacOS Catalina MacBook Pro 2012

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, macos-catalina

System always restarts and cannot run; RAM 8 GB of 16 GB Processor 4

I tried system setting in VirtualBox but still failed:

- RAM 8 and Processor 4
- RAM 6 and Processor 4
- RAM 10 and Processor 4
- RAM 6 and Processor 2
- RAM 8 and Processor 2
- RAM 10 and Processor 2

Answer (score 1):

So far as I know, the Host Machine has to fit the Windows requirements.

Your system from 2012 will not meet the CPU generation requirement (3 years old or newer) and may not meet the TPM requirements.

It may run Windows 10, but Windows 10 came out in 2015, so if the newest version of Windows 10 won't run, then age of machine is likely the reason.

Be sure you have Hardware Virtualization and VT-d enabled for 64-bit systems.

If not all the above, then it is just a bit too old.

If you are able to find an older version of Windows 10, you may be able to get it to install but it may stop updating at some point, and that could be a security risk

Comment: Download Windows 10 Disc Image (ISO File) on Microsoft's Web written like this: Windows 10 2022 Update l Version 22H2,
Isit Windows 10 or Windows 11?

Comment: Your machine may run Windows 10, but not Windows 11

Comment: @Rizal What John is saying is your 2012 system not be able to handle a modern Windows 10 but rather it would only be able to run a Windows 10 version that came out in 2015 and nothing past that.